# Flux seems to cache until the first SSE subscriber

Tags: java, spring-boot, reactive, server-sent-events, flux

I want to achieve the following:

- Provide an endpoint "/sse/bus" that my frontend can use to subscribe to server sent events
- Publish useful events to all subscribers
- Subscribers only get the latest events, only the ones that were published *after* they subscribed

I created the following Flux sink:

```java
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.event.EventListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import reactor.core.publisher.FluxSink;

@Service
public class FEBus implements Consumer<FluxSink<FEMessage>> {

  private final Executor executor;
  private final BlockingQueue<FEMessage> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

  FEBus(@Qualifier("applicationTaskExecutor") Executor executor) {
    this.executor = executor;
  }

  @EventListener
  public void on(FEMessage message) {
    try {
      this.queue.offer(message, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to offer the message to the FEBus: %s".formatted(e));
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void accept(FluxSink<FEMessage> sink) {

    this.executor.execute(() -> {
      while (true) {
        try {
          final var message = queue.take();
          sink.next(message);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
          throw new IllegalStateException(
              "Unable to take a message from the FEBus: %s".formatted(e));
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and a controller for the frontend:

```java
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;

@Controller
public class FEBusController {

  private final Flux<FEMessage> notifications;

  public FEBusController(FEBus febus) {
    this.notifications = Flux.create(febus).share();
    // this.notifications.subscribe().dispose();

  }

  @GetMapping(path = "/sse/bus", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
  public Flux<FEMessage> streamNotifications() {
    return notifications;
  }

}
```

My frontend can successfully subscribe and receives all events, nearly everything works as expected, however:

Until the first subscriber subscribes via the endpoint, the data is cached. The moment the first frontend subscribes, he receives all messages that built up until that moment.

I am aware that [the documentation states](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#reactive.subscribe) "Nothing Happens Until You subscribe()" -- this is confirmed by uncommenting l.13 in the controller.

But it is not clear to me

- how/where the data is cached?
- how to circumvent the behaviour correctly?

Again, the goal is to provide the events that occur *after* the frontend subscribes and ignore all that happened before that.